# force:source:deploy : only error "Unknown"

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, error, force

After a branch merge, while deploying to an org or trying to create a new scratch org, I also see the same following error "unknown"

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -x /tmp/sfdx-hardis-1g1ugd/mainPackage.xml --wait 60 --ignorewarnings --testlevel RunLocalTests
Job ID | 0Af0E00001rOxPESA0
TYPE  PROJECT PATH  PROBLEM
────  ────────────  ───────
                    Unknown
 ›   Warning: sfdx-cli update available from 7.85.1 to 7.93.1.
SOURCE PROGRESS | ████████████████████████████████████████ | 0/0 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ████████████████████████████████████████ | 0/0 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ████████████████████████████████████████ | 0/0 Components
.....
ERROR running force:source:deploy:  Deploy failed.
```

Has anyone already had it ?

Is there a way to have a single clue about what is wrong in the sfdx sources ?

Note: the result is the same undepending i do a force:source:push or a force:source:deploy with a package.xml

Thanks !

**Edit**:

I tried locally a force:source:push with --debug, and in .sfdx.log file, I see a strange error about a not existing file in HOME/.sfdx/sfdx-project.json

```
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"PC00002T","pid":15728,"log":"SfdxProjectJson","level":40,"msg":"The config file: C:\\Users\\nvuillamy\\.sfdx\\sfdx-project.json is not schema valid\nDue to: Validation errors:\nshould have required property 'packageDirectories'","time":"2021-04-01T18:05:05.534Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"PC00002T","pid":15728,"log":"SfdxProjectJson","level":40,"msg":"The config file: C:\\Users\\nvuillamy\\.sfdx\\sfdx-project.json is not schema valid\nDue to: Validation errors:\nshould have required property 'packageDirectories'","time":"2021-04-01T18:05:05.539Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"PC00002T","pid":15728,"log":"SourcePushCommand","level":50,"msg":"[\n  '\\x1B[1mERROR running force:source:push: \\x1B[22m',\n  '\\x1B[31mPush failed.\\x1B[39m'\n]","time":"2021-04-01T18:05:05.569Z","v":0}
```

My sfdx-project.json is the same from the beginning, and is at the root of my repository:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "51.0"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried asking sfdx to show more debug log information? Take a look at [Mohith's blog](https://medium.com/@mohitkumarsrivastav/debugging-tips-for-salesforce-cli-305ca89989b5) for some info.

Comment: have you looked at trying to switch back to using SOAP deploy (`sfdx config:set restDeploy=false --global`) . See general deployment [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/942)

Comment: @PhilW I edited my post with more logs, but it doen't help :/

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I am already using SoapDeloy

Comment: it is referring to the folder where usually the org information is stored:
The config file: C:\\Users\\nvuillamy\\.sfdx\\sfdx-project.json is not schema valid

I don't know what you are doing, but it seems to take things wrong. in the mentioned file have a look, whether its correct or not. it says it misses the "packageDirectories" entry there. Or maybe just delete it, since i have also never seen in a project.json in there^^'

Comment: never saw a project.json there either... except now  :/